# Try to check two values if there are equal

Tags: java, android, if-statement, qr-code

i'm trying to check to values . The first value i get from a QR Code, the second is a String which i have added to my source code. For the QR function iam using the ZXingScannerView Library. Here is my code, but unfortunately my if is going always to else. Here is my Code:

public class Konto  extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

```
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_konto
    );
    ImageButton test = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.testforsql);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(Konto.this);
            setContentView(mScannerView);
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(Konto.this);
            mScannerView.startCamera();

        }
    });


    }

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Log.w("handleResult",result.getText());
  /*  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Konto.this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();*/
    if (result.equals("test")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"works not",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(Konto.this);

}
```

}

Comment: Just a tip, in Java always place the string literal to the right side when comparing strings. eg. `if ("test".equals(result))`. This is to prevent you from getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with API, but don't you need to call

```
result.getText().equals
```

Instead of

```
result.equals
```